# No puedo mostrar modal form

Tags: javascript

Tengo mi plantilla html que me devuelve un menu collapsable, y una opcion deberia mostrar tanto con F2 como presionando un modalform, pero no lo consigo:

```html
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="exit.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
     <script src="includes/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="/gestionn/views/jquery.maskMoney.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <nav class = "navbar" role = "navigation">
         <div class = "navbar-header" >
         
            <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">GESTION WEB</a>
          <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn">M</button>
         </div>
         <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <?php echo " " .$_SESSION ['username']; ?> 
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user" >
                        
                        
                        <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Cerrar Sesion</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
             
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
         </div>

      </nav>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">

        <div id="dismiss">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>MENU PRINCIPAL</h3>
        </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <ul >
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" href="" >
             <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i><span  id="art"> ARTICULO - F2</span>
        </a>
            </ul>
                <ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <ul >
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" href="" >
            <i class="fas fa-wrench"></i><span  id="serv"> SERVICIO - F4</span>
        </a>
            </ul>
                <ul>  
                
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <ul >
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCC" href="" >
             <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i><span  id="CC"> CUENTAS   - F5</span>
        </a>
            </ul></ul></ul>
                <ul>  
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <ul >
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" href="" >
             <i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i><span  id="VENTA"> VENTA   -   F6</span>
        </a>
            </ul> </ul>       
    <li class="dropdown"><a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      <span>ABM</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=cliente&action=index">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>Cliente</span>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=articulo&action=index">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i><span>Articulo</span>
        </a>
               
                </li>
        <li ><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=proveedor&action=index"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>Proveedores</span></a></a></li>
       <!-- <li ><a href="index.php?controller=envase&action=todos"><i class="fas fa-prescription-bottle"></i>Envases</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=medida&action=index"><i class="fas fa-ruler"></i>Medidas</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=canilla&action=index"><i class="fas fa-oil-can"></i>Canillas</a></li> --!>
       <li ><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=user&action=index"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>Usuarios</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i> Estado de cajas</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="opcion" href=""><i class="fas fa-money-check"></i>Chequera</a></li>
        <li><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=caja&action=gasto"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Nuevo Gasto</a></li>
        <li><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=caja&action=abrir"><i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i>Abrir caja</a></li>
        <li><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=caja&action=index"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>Cerrar caja</a></li>
        <li><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=cliente&action=cuenta"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i>Cuenta Corriente</a></li>
        <li><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=caja&action=indexgrande"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i>Caja Grande</a></li>
        <li><a class="opcion" href=""><i class="far fa-credit-card"></i>Posnet</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

<li class="dropdown"><a  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fas fa-store"></i>Compra de stock</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=stock&action=index">Productos</a></li>
        <li><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=stock&action=indexb">Barril</a></li>
        <li><a class="opcion" href="index.php?controller=stock&action=canilla">Cambio de canilla</a></li>
      </ul>
    
    </li>
  </ul>



    </nav>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog"style="width: 75%;">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">BUSQUEDA DE ARTICULO</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="content">

   <?php  if (isset($_GET['controller'])&&isset($_GET['action'])) {

        $controller=$_GET['controller'];

        $action=$_GET['action'];
        if (isset($_GET['id'])){
            
            $id=$_GET['id'];
            call($controller,$action,$id);
        }else{
            
        call($controller,$action,0); }

    }?>
     
    </div>
    <!-- Dark Overlay element -->
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>



   
</body>

</html>
```

Entonces en mi archivo js exit.js que inclui tengo:

```
   $(document).on('keydown', 'body', function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode==115){ //F4

    $('.modal-body').load('contentCC.html',function(){

    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});

   }); }
    if(event.keyCode==113){ //F2

    $('.modal-body').load('content.html',function(){

    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
```

});

Pero no me lo muestra, en la consola del navegador obtengo:

**[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.**

sin embargo no realizo ninguna peticion asincrona. La linea afectada es:

```
    $('.modal-body').load('content.html',function(){
```

Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el mensaje indica que estas usando una función **XMLHttpRequest** obsoleta ("Deprecated").

Estas agregando tres versiones de `jquery` (usa solo la mas actual):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

y 2 versiones de bootstrap (segun tu .css deberias usar solo el .js 3.4 de bootstrap)

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Eso genera graves conflictos.

Te recomiendo agregar en la parte superior los archivos .css, y al pie del html los .js (plugins), y finalmente tu .js personalizado.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!! se soluciono pero no me muestra los glypicons que tenia en el menu

Comment: Glyphicon trabaja con bootstrap 3 por defecto, no retires tu css js de bootstrap 3.4.0, retira el js de bootstrap 4.1.0.